# Is it ok to detach and reattach Vue.js nodes outside a Vue.js document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm using [semantic-ui modal](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html) to manage modals in my app. The modals are all initially placed within a parent div and that div is the root of a Vue.js app. Within the modal content are some Vue components.

Semantic-ui modal `detach()`es the modal div from the DOM and `appendTo()`s it to dimmer div at the root of the site [in order to aid rendering](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/usage). The Vie.js app continues to function as expected which is great, but I wondered if this is a fluke, and if I should be wary of any gotcha's when Vue elements get moved outside of the root Vue element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid technique. All the orthogonal components like Dialog, snackbar, notification, etc. are rendered this way. It works perfectly fine with Vue.js Virtual DOM.

This pattern is so common that there is a library to do this - [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue). It is written by Vue.js core team member.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did come across portal-vue before posting this question which did make me feel like this was an ok technique :) Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Hey be carefull when doing so.
There are edge cases which lead to unwanted behaviors.

When you dynamically attach/detach Modal's using v-if/v-for Vue will loose the reference to your Modal which will lead to unwanted behavior.

Currently we have fixed this by using `detachable: false` so the Modal itself is not moved inside the dimmer.

Comment: Thanks @nativedigital. My modal is backed by a VueX Store module. The component that represents the modal (which stays around and is reused) watches the store for a boolean (isVisible) and when it changes to true the component triggers the modal's show function. It works really well :)